# getKMLcoordinates returns a list of lists instead of a list of segments

Tags: r, gps, kml

I made a cool map once by plotting kml coordinates in R, and overlaying species abundance data on top. When I wrote the code the first time, I used the following to call my list of coordinates:
`spa<-getKMLcoordinates('Perimeter_Track.kml', ignoreAltitude=TRUE)`

`summary(spa)` returns:

```
 Length Class  Mode   
[1,] 128 -none- numeric

[2,] 242 -none- numeric

[3,] 34 -none- numeric

[4,] 126 -none- numeric
```

(the GPS coordinates were a perimeter track measured in 4 chunks, so each list is one of those chunks):
NOW when I run the code again, `summary(spa)` returns:

```
         Length Class  Mode
[1,] 2      -none- list
[2,] 2      -none- list
[3,] 2      -none- list
[4,] 2      -none- list
```

If I convert spa into a dataframe using `as.data.frame()`, I still get this error when I try to use `rbind` to concatenate the 4 chunks into one big track:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

R seems not to be reading the kml file, or only reading part of it.

The list (or dataframe) spa is

```
  c..157.80736808..21.4323436..20.324951171875.
1                                    -157.80737
2                                      21.43234
3                                      20.32495
  c..157.80738216..21.43231443..19.36376953125.
1                                    -157.80738
2                                      21.43231
3                                      19.36377
  c..157.80533605..21.43536092..15.9990234375. c..157.8053208..21.43541138..15.9990234375.
1                                   -157.80534                                  -157.80532
2                                     21.43536                                    21.43541
3                                     15.99902                                    15.99902
  c..157.80998348..21.43706806..15.9990234375.
1                                   -157.80998
2                                     21.43707
3                                     15.99902
  c..157.80997007..21.43711106..17.441162109375.
1                                     -157.80997
2                                       21.43711
3                                       17.44116
  c..157.81074733..21.43717535..13.5958251953125.
1                                      -157.81075
2                                        21.43718
3                                        13.59583
  c..157.81071673..21.43718331..14.076416015625.
1                                     -157.81072
2                                       21.43718
3                                       14.07642
```

Is this an error with maptools or my code? As far as I know, this is the easiest way to convert kml coordinates into coordinates that R can use.  Your help would be much appreciated.

A link to the file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8elanjnst6438v/Perimeter_Track.kml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix has been committed to R-forge, maptools project, revision 232. Please try out after this evening European time:

```
install.packages("maptools", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

which handles this problem. However, I have no idea why you didn't use:

```
library(rgdal)
ogrListLayers(dsn="Perimeter_Track.kml") # to find the layer name
spa1 <- readOGR(dsn="Perimeter_Track.kml", layer="Perimeter_Track.kml")
summary(spa1)
```

This is a SpatialLinesData Frame, that can be used in lots of ways with no further effort. It also tackles the tabs without difficulty. To get to your input into the form returned by the ad-hoc maptools function, do:

```
o0 <- coordinates(spa1)
o1 <- lapply(o0, function(x) do.call("rbind", x))
library(maptools) # SVN revision >= 232
spa <- getKMLcoordinates('Perimeter_Track.kml', ignoreAltitude=TRUE)
all.equal(o1, spa)
```

Comment: I didn't use rgdal because there isn't a binary for Mac OS X readily available. I've been working on getting the package to install anyway (see my previous .kml-related cries for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907217/creating-x-and-y-distance-coordinates-for-r-from-a-kml-file)

Answer (score 0):

Your example file contains tab characters that are not expected by the `getKMLcoordinates` function (maptools version 0.8-14).

If you make a small modification it works as expected. I've put comments where my addition is:

```
getKMLcoordinates_01 <- function (kmlfile, ignoreAltitude = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(kmlfile)) 
        stop("kmlfile is missing")
    kml <- paste(readLines(kmlfile, encoding = "UTF-8"), collapse = " ")
    re <- "<coordinates> *([^<]+?) *<\\/coordinates>"

    ## ++ new code
    ## remove tabs first
    kml <- gsub("\\t", "", kml)
    ##   

    mtchs <- gregexpr(re, kml)[[1]]
    coords <- list()
    for (i in 1:(length(mtchs))) {

        kmlCoords <- unlist(strsplit(gsub(re, "\\1", substr(kml, 
            mtchs[i], (mtchs[i] + attr(mtchs, "match.length")[i])), 
            perl = TRUE), split = " "))
        m <- t(as.matrix(sapply(kmlCoords, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, 
            ","))), USE.NAMES = FALSE)))
        if (!ignoreAltitude && dim(m)[2] != 3) 
            message(paste("no altitude values for KML object", 
                i))
        coords <- append(coords, ifelse(ignoreAltitude, list(m[, 
            1:2]), list(m)))
    }
    coords
}

spa <- getKMLcoordinates_01("Perimeter_Track.kml")
summary(spa)
     Length Class  Mode   
[1,] 192    -none- numeric
[2,] 363    -none- numeric
[3,]  51    -none- numeric
[4,] 189    -none- numeric
```

```
R version 2.15.0 Patched (2012-05-05 r59321)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  compiler  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_0.7-8     maptools_0.8-14 lattice_0.20-6  sp_0.9-98       foreign_0.8-49 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.0  tools_2.15.0
```

Comment: I have now attached it to the question. I hope it helps.